# WiFi issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04, suspend

Using 22.04 on a Dell Precision , just upgraded kernel to `Linux 6.1.4-060104-generic` but to no avail. Basically, there's no connection after a boot, or after returning from suspend. On boot I managed to work around this by executing `sudo ufw reload`. Also, for whatever reason there *is* a connection after a suspend (not after boot) if my machine is connected to an external display.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu, as the 6.1 kernel you mention is not a *supported* Ubuntu kernel

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I'm using Ubuntu. Just updated the kernel as it seemed to be the latest version listed via the Ubuntu mainline kernel installer app... Figured it would be supported

Comment: It's a *testing* kernel.  The supported GA kernel is 5.15, next HWE jump is to 5.19 (*available first via -edge*) but will roll out soon with 22.04.2, with 6.0 expected at 22.04.3....

Comment: Thanks, I had the 5.15 kernel before upgrading to the newer testing one. The problem persisted in both, unfortunately.